# Primary Key(count) for each user - Django

Tags: python, django, count, primary-key

I have a Django website and part of it lists data in rows with the primary key in one of the columns. This works great except for when I have separate users. I'm using foreign keys in each model to separate the different user's data. My problem is that the data for each user has to have a number in the column that increments numerically and does not have any spacing, for instance, 1,2,3,5 is bad. If User1 is uploading data and halfway through User2 uploads a row of data then if I use the primary key the numbers will not be in numerical order for each user and will read 1,2,3,5 for User1 and 4 for User2. I tried forloop counter but I need the numbers all the be assigned to the row and not change if one is deleted. Ive been at this for 2 weeks and am having a really hard time describing my problem. I think I need somesort of Custom User Primary Key, a primary key for each user. Any help at this point is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Add a field to track this user_sequence_number. Then use something like https://github.com/aaugustin/django-sequences to get the next ID per user and store it in the record. Seems like overkill but if they must be sequential then you need something transactional, even an auto increment pk can potentially have gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out after about a week.

models.py:

```
class Sheet_Building(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True, related_name="Building", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    count_building = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Date')
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Time')
    inspection_type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=INSPECTION_TYPE_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Type')
    flname = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspector')
    report_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Report Date')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=29, choices=DEPARTMENT_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Department')
    responsible_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Responsible Person')
    building_address = models.CharField(max_length=52, choices=BUILDING_ADDRESS, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Building and Address')
    floor = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=FLOOR_LEVEL_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Floor / Level')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Area / Room')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LOCATION_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Location')
    priority = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Priority')
    hazard_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=HAZARD_LEVEL_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Hazard Level')
    concern = models.CharField(max_length=31, choices=CONCERN_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Concern')
    codes = models.CharField(max_length=51, choices=CODES_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Element and Code')
    correction = models.TextField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Corrective Action')
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Image', upload_to='gallery')
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Inspector's note")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.flname or 'None'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_building')
```

view.py:

```
def adddata_building(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = SheetForm_Building(response.POST, response.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = response.user  #User
            if Sheet_Building.objects.filter(user=response.user).values_list('count_building'):
                instance.count_building = Sheet_Building.objects.filter(user=response.user).aggregate(count_building=Max('count_building'))['count_building'] + 1 #Count
            else:
                instance.count_building = 1
            instance.save()
            response.user.Building.add(instance)
            return redirect('list_building')
    else:
        form = SheetForm_Building()

    return render(response, 'sheets/add_data/add_data_building.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
    {{ post.count_building }}
{% enfor %}
```